# Resetting specific values to defaults in My.Settings

Tags: vb.net

I know about `My.Settings.Reset()`, but that resets all values. I would like to reset only two, date and user.
How would I do that?

Comment: I didn't find anything that would allow this in a quick perusal of the online help.

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
Dim defaultValue = My.Settings.Properties(NameOf(My.Settings.SomeSetting)).DefaultValue
```

Comment: Did you set the default value? Did you use the right setting?

Comment: Yes, I have set a default value, yes I have used the right setting.

Comment: Which version of vs you have? As Karen stated, Nameof started with Vs2015, so try instead My.Settings.Properties("SomeSetting")

Answer (score 0):

[NameOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) started with VS2015. When in doubt use

```
My.Settings.Properties("SomeSetting").DefaultValue
```

Instead of

```
My.Settings.Properties(NameOf(My.Settings.SomeSetting)).DefaultValue
```